# Return String Similarity Scores between two String Columns - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to build a search based results, where in I will have an input dataframe having one row and I want to compare with another dataframe having almost 1 million rows. I'm using a package called [Record Linkage](https://recordlinkage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/about.html)

However, I'm not able to handle typos. Lets say I have "HSBC" in my original data and the user types it as "HKSBC", I want to return "HSBC" results only. On comparing the string similarity distance with jarowinkler I get the following results:

```
from pyjarowinkler import distance
distance.get_jaro_distance("hksbc", "hsbc", winkler=True, scaling=0.1)
>> 0.94
```

However, I'm not able to give "HSBC" as an output, so I want to create a new column in my pandas dataframe where in I'll compute the string similarity scores and take that part of the score which has a score above a particular threshold.

Also, the main bottleneck is that I have almost 1 million data, so I need to compute it really fast.

P.S. I have no intentions of using `fuzzywuzzy`, preferable either of `Jaccard` or `Jaro-Winkler`

P.P.S. Any other ideas to handle typos for search based thing is also acceptable

Comment: Why are you not able to give "HSBC" as an output? Couldn't you just use the string in your database which has the highest similarity to the user input?

Comment: That is what my question is all about,  how can create a new column with the string similarity scores and select particular part which satisfies my threshold value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it through record linkage only. So basically it does an initial indexing and generates candidate links (You can refer to the documentation on "SortedNeighbourhoodindexing" for more info), i.e. it does a multi-indexing between the two dataframes that needs to be compared, which I did manually.

So here is my code:

```
import recordlinkage

df['index'] = 1 # this will be static since I'll have only one input value
df['index_2'] = range(1, len(df)+1)

df.set_index(['index', 'index_2'], inplace=True)

candidate_links=df.index

df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df.index = range(1, len(df)+1)

# once the candidate links has been generated you need to reset the index and compare with the input dataframe which basically has only one static index, i.e. 1

compare_cl = recordlinkage.Compare()
compare_cl.string('Name', 'Name', label='Name', method='jarowinkler') # 'Name' is the column name which is there in both the dataframe

features = compare_cl.compute(candidate_links,df_input,df) # df_input is the i/p df having only one index value since it will always have only one row
print(features)
                       Name
index   index_2 
  1      13446       0.494444
         13447       0.420833
         13469       0.517949
```

Now I can give a filter like this:

```
features = features[features['Name'] > 0.9] # setting the threshold which will filter away my not-so-close names.
```

Then,

```
df = df[df['index'].isin(features['index_2'])
```

This will sort my results and give me the final dataframe which has a name score greater than a particular threshold set by the user.